# Remove an array from an array list

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have an array list, like this one: http://pastebin.com/UKrrVyUs
I need to remove the **array4** because his category is the same of the **array1**

I was thinking to use unset but he remove the array leaving the position empty, how i can remove the array4 generating a new array list like:

```
Array( [0] => Array () [1] => Array () [2] => Array () [3] => Array ()  [4] => Array () )
```

where the `array[4]` is the previously `Array[5]` ?

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php